# react native access function from root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

In my React Native app, I am currently developing a custom toast. At the root of my app is my toast component. I want to be able to call this specific components `callToast()` function from anywhere in my app. I have attempted to set up a context that stores the ref of this root component and then access that context through a consumer anywhere in my app, but it is not working. My first iteration looks like this below:

App/Root screen

```
export const ToastContext = React.createContext()

export const useToast = () => {
   return ToastContext.toastRef;
};


state = {
        ref : null
    };
```

```
<ToastContext.Provider value = {this.state.ref}>
  <>
    <AppContainer />
    <Toast ref = {r => this.setState({ref : r})}/>
  </>
</ToastContext.Provider>
```

My toast component

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet, Dimensions, Image, TouchableOpacity, Animated
} from 'react-native';


const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

const HEIGHT_OF_TOAST = 60
let TOAST_REF;

export const Toast = ({}) => {

  const animate = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
  const animateInOut = animate.interpolate({
    inputRange : [0,1],
    outputRange : [-(HEIGHT_OF_TOAST + 10), 30]
  })
  const callToast = () => {
    Animated.timing(animate, {
      toValue : 1,
      duration : 200
    }).start()
  }

  return (
    <Animated.View style = {[styles.shadow,
        {position : 'absolute', opacity : animate, bottom : animateInOut, right : 20, borderRadius : 12, left : 20,
          backgroundColor : "#fff", height : HEIGHT_OF_TOAST}]}>
      <Text>Toast</Text>
    </Animated.View>

  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shadow : {
    shadowColor: "#333",
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 4,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.4,
    shadowRadius: 7.2,

    elevation: 9,
  }
})
```

Dummy component where I try to call my toast

```
//At start of component
const toast = useToast()


<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => toast.callToast()}>
              <Text>Test Toast</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

When attempting to do this, I get an error: undefined is not an object evaluating toast.callToast

When using it from the contexts consumer, I get a context.value is undefined error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, or best practices for exposing a sort of function.